# Procedimientos MYSQL

Tags: mysql, base-de-datos, stored-procedure, wamp

```
delimiter //

create procedure elimdato(in id_emple int(6),cp varchar(5))

begin

DELETE FROM empleado WHERE cp=cp;
end //

call elimdato(1,40855);
```

Al momento de ejecutar este procedimiento, me borra toda la información de la tabla empleado, quisiera saber como eliminar solo los datos especificados de la columna.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El problema se te presenta porque tienes un campo llamado **cp** y de igual forma has creado una variable local en MySQL que posee el mismo nombre. Esto en MySql es un error ya que el gestor termina interpretando la referencia al campo de la tabla como la variable recien creada.

```
Where cp=cp
```

Lo estás interpretando como el campo **cp** de la tabla empleado sea igual a **cp** que es la variable definida localmente para el stored procedure.

Ahora MySql lo "entiende" como la variable local definida **cp** sea igual a la variable definida **cp**

Solucionas tu problema cambiando el nombre de tu variable local por otro. Por ejemplo:

```
delimiter //

create procedure elimdato(in id_emple int(6),nocp varchar(5))

begin

DELETE FROM empleado WHERE cp=nocp;
end //

call elimdato(1,40855);
```

Espero sea de ayuda. Un Saludo!

Comment: Muchas gracias! amigo, tu respuesta fue de gran ayuda, ahora para no volver a cometer el mismo error, es poner la variable con otro nombre ;)

Comment: @DanielHorta De nada, me alegra que ha sido útil. Un saludo!